# Android Maps Utility extra functionality (Clustering)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am reading the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/) and in order to initialise the clustering manager I need to put this line of code:

```
getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

My question is what I need to do if I have more things to do when the camera changes position (for example bringing more items/markers from server)?

For marker click event, the documentation states the following:

> If you want to add specific functionality in response to a marker
>   click event, set the map's OnMarkerClickListener() to the
>   ClusterManager, since ClusterManager implements the listener.

I am not sure I understand what is said in this sentence and if it will work for the camera change event.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually call onCameraChange:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);

            // Your custom code here

        }
    });
```

Comment: This methods realy go on camara change, but add new markers dosen't do nothing.